# Is it possible to trigger AKS Pods from Azure Data Factory

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory, azure-aks

Is it possible to trigger a job in AKS Pod from Azure Datafactory , Do we have any connectors from ADF to AKS

Comment: No, not out-of-the box. Tell me, what kind of trigger would you have wanted? What would be passed to the pod and what result would you expect?

Comment: If the answer was helpful , You can [Accept it as an Answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work), ( click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in.) so that others who encounter the same issue can find this solution and fix their problem

Answer (score 0):

There is no direct connector for AKS, however, you can share your idea [here](https://feedback.azure.com/d365community/forum/1219ec2d-6c26-ec11-b6e6-000d3a4f032c#)

What you can do is use, `Web Activity` to send API call to submit a job using an image.

You can refer a similar approach mentioned in an external doc [here](https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/ultimate-evolution-spark-data-pipelines-azure-kubernetes-kenny-bui)